# schtasks on Windows 7

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I have developed a VBScript which i want to run with schtask. This script creates a log of its execution in form of a text file. My script works fine when I run it manually and with the scheduled task on Windows XP machine, problem is with Windows 7 machine. It doesn't create log file on Windows 7 machine with scheduled task. Tried putting the path in "\path\" form, also tried mentioning username and password of the logged in user. Nothing worked. 
Looking forward for your expert comments. 
Thanks in advance.